# Paste formatted Python code in command line

Tags: python

I want to run Python code from an [example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html#scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans) in the [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) shell. Unfortunately the statement I want to paste has lines starting with `...`. Is there an easy way to run such a statement without having to manually remove the `...`? I know that other shells exist, but I don't want to have to try getting them working with Anaconda

```
>>> features  = array([[ 1.9,2.3],
...                    [ 1.5,2.5],
...                    [ 0.8,0.6],
...                    [ 0.4,1.8],
...                    [ 0.1,0.1],
...                    [ 0.2,1.8],
...                    [ 2.0,0.5],
...                    [ 0.3,1.5],
...                    [ 1.0,1.0]])
```

Comment: This is where notepad++ shines as the best text editor ever.

Comment: @ShashankGupta: Can you explain?

Comment: Notepad++ lets you delete columns from a select number of rows. You can literally take out all those dots and spaces by just holding down alt, highlighting it and hitting delete (pretty much a 2 second operation). I'm sure there are other advanced text editors out there that let you do the same.

Comment: @Josh At just the slightest glance, it looks very slick. Thanks for the reference, I'm downloading it now.

Answer (score 5):

Python's native [doctest parser](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/doctest.html#doctest.DocTestParser) is used to dealing with those pesky repr prompts. :)

```
>>> from doctest import DocTestParser
>>> repr_code = '''
... >>> features  = array([[ 1.9,2.3],
... ...                    [ 1.5,2.5],
... ...                    [ 0.8,0.6],
... ...                    [ 0.4,1.8],
... ...                    [ 0.1,0.1],
... ...                    [ 0.2,1.8],
... ...                    [ 2.0,0.5],
... ...                    [ 0.3,1.5],
... ...                    [ 1.0,1.0]])
... '''
>>> p = DocTestParser()
>>> code = next(filter(None, p.parse(repr_code.strip()))) # Filter out the useless parts
>>> print(code.source)
features  = array([[ 1.9,2.3],
               [ 1.5,2.5],
               [ 0.8,0.6],
               [ 0.4,1.8],
               [ 0.1,0.1],
               [ 0.2,1.8],
               [ 2.0,0.5],
               [ 0.3,1.5],
               [ 1.0,1.0]])
>>> array = list # Because it's cheaper than numpy
>>> exec(code.source) # If you're feeling very lucky...
>>> len(features)
9
```

Comment: I guess that works, but they really need to build something into the shell

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you correctly: you want to remove dots.
I would do it this way:

1. open up `vim`
2. press `i`
3. paste the text (`ctrl+v`)
4. press `ESC` to exit `Insert mode`
5. press `ctrl+v` to enter `Visual Block`
6. move cursor up to select all dots
7. press `x` to remove them.

Than do what ever you want with this formated text (can copy and paste)

Comment: That works, I'm just surprised that the console doesn't have an easy manner of running code copied from the web